# Regarding the R packages that share the similar functionalities of NLTK toolkit

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, natural-language

Are there any R packages that share the similar functionalities of NLTK toolkit?

Comment: Are you familiar with http://rseek.org/?  Bookmark it and start your searches for R packages there. (Afterwards you can come here and ask really focused questions. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no single R package which is as comprehensive as NLTK, but there are a number of packages which provide similar functionality. The [Natural Language Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) at CRAN is a good place to start, especially if you have a particular goal in mind. For general purpose NLP tasks, the most useful packages are probably [openNLP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/index.html), which provides an interface to the Java package OpenNLP, and [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html), which provides basic quantitative tools for text mining.